# How to get impression from google ads using google-ads-node( met one issue; INVALID CUSTOMER ID even though it is set correctly.)

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-ads-api

Hope you are safe and good for this pandemic time.
I am developing some functional to fetch data from google ads using google-ads-node.
But for now I met one issue.

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid customer ID '... .... ...'.
```

However it is set correctly on ads account.
[image]
Please understand me messy picture.
The code I used like this.

```
const auth = await authenticateGoogle(`keys/${process.env.GOOGLE_YT3_API_CREDENTIAL_PATH}`, 'installed');
  const client = new GoogleAdsClient({
    access_token: auth.credentials.access_token,
    developer_token: process.env.DEV_TOKEN,
    parseResults: true,
  });

  const service = client.getService("GoogleAdsService", { useStreaming: true });
  const request = new SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest();
  request.setQuery(`
    SELECT
      campaign.resource_name,
      metrics.impressions,
      segments.date
    FROM 
      campaign
    WHERE 
      segments.date BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2020-01-01"
  `);
  request.setCustomerId(process.env.CUSTOMER_ID);

  const call = service.searchStream(request);
    const chunks = [];

    call.on("error", err => reject(err));
    call.on("data", (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
    call.on("end", () => resolve(chunks));
```

Would you help me how I can figure out this issue please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need is to pass the CustomerID without dash (-). More specifically, you just need passing the CustomerID with `XXXXXXXXXX` format instead of `XXX-XXX-XXXX`.

Comment: You dear stack overflow user, deserves a medal. I haven't found that anywhere in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

google-ads-api need client_id and login_customer_id.

i think CUSTOMER_ID need to change  as "client_customer_Id" not a "login_customer_id"

Answer (score 0):

For the ones that ended up here in 2021+.. the "google-ads-node" does not recieve any more support from Opteo, they now support the "google-ads-api" lib that themselves made.